# cannot start any SQL2005 services

Tags: sql-server, login

When installing SQL server 2005, i provisioned a domain account to have the logon rights to SQL during the configuration wizard.  however when i log into the machine as the domain account (admin) I cannot start any services related to sql server

I get Error1069 the service did not start due to a logon error.

I added the local administrator to the local groups that relate to sql that also included the domain account.

the domain account also has administrator privileges on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the credientials used for the services themselves are incorrect (ie: wrong password).  Check with Services.msc and ensure the right username and password are being used for the services.

Here's a [MS KB article (282254)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282254) that may help.

Blurb:

> When you restart Microsoft SQL Server
>   or SQL Server Agent, the service may
>   fail to start with the following error
>   message:
>
> Error 1069: The service did not start
>   due to a logon failure.
>
> This problem occurs because the
>   password for the SQL Server startup
>   service account or the SQL Server
>   Agent startup service account is not
>   correct. This problem can occur when
>   the password for the account is
>   changed but the password information
>   was not updated for the SQL Server
>   service or the SQL Server Agent
>   service.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I made sure that the password was correct for the SQL services.

i feel awfully foolish now :D

Comment: Don't feel too bad, it happens all the time. ;)